# Tomcat has went faulty in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat8

I have Eclipse Mars installed in Windows 7 professional and installed Tomcat 8 which I then imported into Eclipse.  This all worked really well but then for some reason Tomcat refuses to start when I run a JSP file through the server.  The first error message at the top of the stack trace in the Console is;

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-
nio-8081"]
```

The only thing I can think caused this is I started Tomcat 8 using the startup.bat in the bin folder, then after this it went faulty.  I have tried deleting the Tomcat server from Eclipse and re-importing it but that didn't work.  I have Tomcat 8 set up with port 8081 because 8080 is already used and checked the server.xml file at the first connector still says port 8081.

How do I resolve this please?  I have added all the main message outputs in the console.  However, the ones concerning the filter I don't think are the problem because I removed the filter tag section from the applications web.xml file and the other errors persisted.

SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection

SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8081]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8081]]

SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection

SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8010]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8010]]

#### Two below concern the filter in web.xml

SEVERE: Exception starting filter CH_13LogFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: action.CH_13LogFilter

SEVERE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

NOTE: I have also found that this only occurs in one project in Eclipse.  If I run other projects through the Tomcat server in Eclipse it works fine!!  But I still can't see what has changed in this project.

Comment: What are the rest of the error messages?

Comment: Kind of appropriate cat speak. Tomcat haz error bads ...

Comment: @nitind I have added other error details from Console.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How very odd - but one worth remembering.  Once I had tried running a different project through Tomcat in Eclipse the project with the problem is now working fine!!